# How large would a Strix's wingspan be?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, races

I'm kind of enamoured with the **[Strix](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/uncommon-races/arg-strix)** race from the Pathfinder book, *Advanced Races* and I'm trying to figure out how large an average male's wing span would be.

I think using [Warren Worthington III](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnEZ4.jpg) as a reference could be helpful - I couldn't find his wing span anywhere online, but it looks to be each wing is 7-9' long and maybe 4-5 wide based on comaprison to his 6' height.

Do you suppose it would be safe to estimate that each Strix has a wingspan from around 16-21' from tip to tip? If not, what is their wingspan?

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of arbitrary. Why do you want to know?

Eyeballing a fictional bird-man is certainly a valid way to go most of the time. You won't get an exact, consistent number because the artists are just going by "what looks right in this situation." But you'll get a rough number that results in a nice look.

[This site](http://www.wired.com/2012/01/why-cant-humans-fly-like-birds/) makes a guess based on the weight:wingspan ratio of several birds, and comes up with 6.7 meters (~21 feet). There are other factors that aren't considered, but they're unlikely to be important.

The [Pathfinder Wiki](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Strix) suggests a tiny 12-foot wingspan. This looks to be just slightly smaller than the wingspan on the image for the wiki. Perhaps they meant 12-foot *wings*? That would give a span of 24 feet... But be much larger than the wings of the wiki image.

*Mechanically*, no matter how large a Strix's wings are, it's still a medium creature. Which means it occupies a single 5'x5'x5' cube on the battlefield, and has a reach of 5'.